# Make Gmail messages disappear from a label after they are read

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I have a filter on my Gmail account that puts messages from certain email addresses under a label "Job" omitting the "Received".

Is it possible to make these messages appear also in "Received" **until I read them**? (then they should only appear in "Job")

**UPDATE**

Filtered emails flow:

gmail > Job label [it doesn't show up in Received]

Desired flow:

gmail > Received [stays here until I read it] > [I read the message] > Job [no longer shows up in Received]

Comment: Could you explain this in a bit more detail? What do you mean by saying 'omitting the "Received"' ? It would be great if you could explain the flow of an email with these filters being applied to it.

Comment: @AshutoshJindal take a look at the update

Comment: Filters are only triggered when a message is received. Any other state change can't trigger a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly with filters, no.

You can approximate this by using the Multiple Inboxes feature.

Make the query string for one of the inbox panes something like this:

```
label:Job is:unread
```

You should also be able to do the counterpart to that:

```
label:Job -is:unread
```

The `-` is a NOT operator.

With this you should have two special inboxes (that appear in addition to your regular inbox), one with messages labeled "Job" that haven't been read, and the other labeled "Job" where they have been read.